# protractor- difference between toBe(truth) and toBeTruthy()

Tags: protractor, assertions, angularjs-e2e

as the title says-
is there a difference between (for example)

```
 expect(element).isDisplayed().toBeTruthy();
```

and

```
 expect(element).isDisplayed().toBe(truth);
```

and if so what is the difference?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Many things are `Truthy` (i.e. anything that is not one of: false, 0, "", undefined, null, NaN).
So

```
expect('apple').toBeTruthy();
```

passes. But:

```
expect('apple').toBe(true);
```

fails.

That being said, if you know you are testing a boolean, to me using `toBeTruthy` looks nicer.

Comment: thanks, but not sure I've understood. so 'toBeTruthy()' is for boolean? and what is 'toBe(true)' then?

Comment: No, both toBeTruthy and toBe can be for anything. `toBe` only passes if it's a direct match, but `toBeTruthy` passes for any truthy value. Maybe read this: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-testing-with/9781449356729/_yes_or_no_tobetruthy_tobefalsy.html

Comment: If you know the result should be `true`, you might as well not test it at all. The point of testing is to deal with unexpected situations. Thus, use `toBe(true)` just like you'd always use `===` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is not a new question I thought it deserves an exact answer.

```
expect('apple').toBe(true);
```

evaluates to 'apple' === true. (actual === expected in the jasmine code)
I would prefer

```
expect('apple').toBe('apple');
```

That way you know you are not getting an 'orange'.  On the other hand.

```
expect('apple').toBeTruthy();
```

evaluate 'apple' as !!'apple' (!!actual in the jasmine code).  So not not 'apple'